# Django: How to filter out sub elements

Tags: django, django-queryset

Here's my model:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    published = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.headline
```

There's an external function, on which I do not have access that basically perform the following:

```
def printBlogs(blogs):
    for blog in blogs:
        print blog.name
        for entry in blog.entry_set.all():
            print " *",entry.headline,":", entry.published
```

The following code

```
from weblogs.models import Blog, Entry
r = Blog.objects.all()
printBlogs(r)
```

produces

```
 Blog1
  * Article 1 : True
  * Article 2 : True
  * Article 3 : False
 Blog2
  * Article 1 : True
  * Article 2 : False
  * Article 3 : False
```

What is the proper code to have the following result (remember that I do not have access to printBlogs)

```
 Blog1
  * Article 1 : True
  * Article 2 : True
 Blog2
  * Article 1 : True
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest and most efficient way is to filter first:

```
blog.entry_set.filter(published=True)
```

Or, you can simply use an if statement:

```
if entry.published:
    print entry
```

Comment: I do not have access to the printBlog function. I'm trying to have r containing only what's needed.

Comment: Why do you not have access to it? Where's it at? If you can't alter that method, *and* you can't simply create your own better method, then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
for o in queryset:
    if not results.has_key(o.name):
       results[o.name] = list()
    if not (...check if Z):
       results[o.name].append(o)

for a in results:
    print a
    for b in results[a]:
        print b.state
```

Suppose you have models:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    mod_date = models.DateTimeField()
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    n_comments = models.IntegerField()
    n_pingbacks = models.IntegerField()
    rating = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.headline
```

and you want to exclude all blogs that have name "test"

You would run the code:

Entry.objects.exclude(**blog**__name='test')

and it would write query:

```
SELECT ... FROM `entry` INNER JOIN `blog` ON (`entry`.`blog_id` = `blog`.`id`) WHERE NOT (`blog`.`name` = test )
```

Comment: Your answer creates a new result object which is not a QuerySet, but a  dictionary.

Comment: its just used for reformatting the results from database that can be later in template. However what you're trying to achieve exactly I'm not sure.. paste more of your code.

Comment: I've rephrased the question in the hope of making it clearer.

Comment: i updated my post, see if you can get what you want trough that example.

Comment: Your solution works for filtering obj on the first level, I'd like to filter objs on the second level. I've included enough sources to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`aobjs = [b.a for b in B.objects.exclude(state='Z')]`

Or

`aobj.b_set.exclude(state='Z')`

Comment: aobjs is a list, and I need a QuerySet. 
I've rephrased the question in the hope of making it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Change `Blog.objects.all()` with `Blog.objects.filter(entry__published=True)`

That should do the trick!